# How do I use a for- loop through 10 radio buttons to see which one is checked

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, eventhandler

Basically I have 10 radio buttons and when I click on one, I want a messagebox to pop up with the number associated with that radioButton. However, I do not want to just go through each radio button seperately and add an if radioButton1.checked then messageBox.show("1") for example. 
I have created one event handler called CheckRadioButton which will handle all 10 button event but my for loop does not seem to work... Here is the code

```
Public Class Form1

Dim ListOFNames() As RadioButton = {RadioButton1, RadioButton2, RadioButton3, RadioButton4, RadioButton5, RadioButton6, RadioButton7, RadioButton8, RadioButton9,
RadioButton10}


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub
Private Sub CheckRadioButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, RadioButton3.CheckedChanged,
RadioButton4.CheckedChanged, RadioButton5.CheckedChanged, RadioButton6.CheckedChanged, RadioButton7.CheckedChanged, RadioButton8.CheckedChanged, RadioButton9.CheckedChanged, RadioButton10.CheckedChanged
    For counter = 0 To 9
        If ListOFNames(counter).Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show(counter)

        End If
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged

End Sub

Private Sub TabPage1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: No need to loop.  that mysterious `sender As Object` event param is the one that resulted in the event.  Cast it to a `RedioButton` and get the name or whatever you are after

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. How would I cast?

Comment: Dim rb as radiobutton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton) then use if rb is... or if rb.name=... etc.    (You can use If sender is RadioButton1 etc. Without casting)

Comment: Hey guys I have a new question. This is my new code:
MessageBox.Show(sender.text)

So i click on radiobutton1 for example, and the message says 1, but then i click on the second button for example and the message says 1, i close it and then it says 2. Why does the message show up twice/.

Comment: ah nvm thx for the help guys!

Comment: If you haver a new question then post a new question, not a comment on an existing question.  If this question is resolved then accept the answer that resolved it.  If there isn't one, post your own solution and accept that.  That way, everyone knows that you no longer need an answer and anyone with a similar question can see the solution.

Comment: If `sender.Text` works, then you didnt cast it and need to set `Option Strict On` - Object does not have a text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form39
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton5.CheckedChanged, RadioButton4.CheckedChanged, RadioButton3.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged 'add more RadioButton  CheckedChanged event here
    Dim radio As Object = sender
    Dim radiobox = CType(radio, RadioButton)
    '// radiobox was checked
    '// do whatever you want to do next

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop between radioboxes in form to check radioboxes checked situation.